# Calcular média aritmética de um vetor

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

matriz = []
medias = []
alunos=1

while True:  
    print("Informe o número do aluno ou um valor negativo para terminar:")
    valor=int(input('Digite o número do aluno: '))
    if valor<0:
        break
    else:
        alunos=1
        linha=[valor]
        media1=[]
        media2=[]
        media3=[]
        media4=[]
        media5=[]
        media6=[]

        for i in range(0,3,1): #Notas disciplina 1
            n1=float(input("Informe as notas da disciplina 1: "))
            linha.append(n1)
            media1.append(n1)
        media1.mean()
        print(media1)
```

Comment: Seu objeto `media1` é uma lista do Python, que não possui um método chamado `mean`. O que você precisa não é de `media = np.mean(media1)`?

Comment: Exatamente! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução #1:** Usando `sum()` e `len()`

```
vetor = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0 ]
print( sum(vetor) / float(len(vetor)) )
```

**Solução #2:** Usando `lambda`

```
vetor = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0 ]
print( reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, vetor) / float(len(vetor)) )
```

**Solução #3:** Módulo `statistics`

```
from statistics import mean
vetor = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0 ]
print( mean(vetor) )
```

**Solução #4:** Módulo `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
vetor = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0 ]
print( np.mean(vetor) )
```

Saída:

```
4.5
```